# Setting a UITableViewCell subview tag property

Tags: iphone, uitableview, subview

I have a UITableView, cells of which are customised in a NIB file so I can have a UILabel and UITextField.

Therefore my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SectionCustomCell *cell = (SectionCustomCell *)[tableView       
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Section"];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SectionCustomCell"                                                       
                            owner:self                                               
                            options:nil];

    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    // Set the label value
    [[cell inputLabel] setText:@"something"];

    // Set the textfield tag property
}
```

Therefore for a given section/row I am going to assign some text to the UILabel, defined as **inputLabel**, and have a UITextField, called **inputTextField** get some text from the user.

My plan is to set the **tag** property of the UITextField so I can determine which field I am getting in the delegate **textFieldDidEndEditing**.

Now my problem, if I put this code:

```
 UITextField *textField = nil;
 for (UIView *oneView in cell.contentView.subviews) 
 {
    if ([oneView isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]])
       textField = (UITextField *)oneView;
 }
 textField.tag = [indexPath row];
```

the tag property is set correctly.  (I know this from a NSLog statement).  However if I do the following it is **not** set correctly.  It is always 1 as defined in IB.

```
 cell.inputTextField.tag = [indexPath row];
```

but to me this *should* work. I am doing the same principle with the setting the labels text. Can someone help me to understand why it doesn't work?

I'm new to iOS so go gentle :-)

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have connected the textfield and the IBOutlet in IB. 
If that doesnt work try putting this in the code:

```
NSLog(@"%i", cell.inputTextField == nil);
```

If it prints `1` to the console then it means the inputTextField is nil so somewhere between the nib file, your custom class and the tableview datasource the connection is getting lost. But as I first said this is most likely the textfield is not connected properly in IB.

Comment: Thank you - as always I hadn't connected the outlet properly. doh!